# Full clone of encrypted disk not bootable on other computers

Tags: backup, dd, uefi, bootable

I have made a full disk clone of my encrypted S2 disk to an external USB disk with

```
dd if=/dev/nvme0n1 of=/dev/sdb status=progress
```

The S2 disk was not mounted when cloning, I used a live distribution on a USB stick.

When I reboot the computer boots from the USB drive. But when plugging the USB drive into other computers (I have tried 3) the drive is not bootable. I suspect the S2 disk is somehow used during the boot process?

How can I make the USB drive bootable?

I tried to make the first partition bootable with `parted`

```
parted set 1 boot on
```

but that did not help. Alos, `fdisk` complained about "GPT PMBR size mismatch", but that seems to have been fixed by running `parted`.

There are some other questions concerning disk cloning on Stack Exchange, but they don't seem to have the problem that the disk is not bootable at all.

EDIT: I have now tried cloning with Clonezilla, but get the same problem.

EDIT2: @njboot's comment make me suspect this problem is related to UEFI boot.

Comment: You may need to [bless](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/bless/) it - check out the man page.

Comment: @njboot Seems like `bless` is a Mac/BSD tool? But `bless` hinted me to this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting#Non-Mac_x86_64_UEFI_systems Do I need to do something with `efibootmgr`?

Comment: Next time don't use `dd` like that; it will take forever and then some. Instead, use `cat`. Or if you must use `dd` ensure you're using a decent block size, such as `dd bs=32M...`

Comment: @roaima `dd` with default block size wasn't noticeably slower than Clonezilla, which I assume use decent defaults.

Answer (score 1):

I made a little bit of progress on this, so here is a partial answer. I used this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/380564/210203.

In one of the partitions on the external drive, I copied `EFI/debian/grubx64.efi` to `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`. I also had to activate (hybrid) UEFI boot on the computers where I tried to boot from the backup.

Both laptops now boot from the backup disk. They hanged at different places in the boot process though. I don't know if caused by missing drivers or perhaps getting access to the encrypted partition.

I may try later to physically remove the disk I am trying to backup and see if that computer boots from the backup.